# Write markup extension as nested element

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, resourcedictionary, markup-extensions

Is it possible to write markup extension as nested element rather than attribute? I am trying to use `Boolean` as key for `ResourceDictionary` entries.

Current code where `ResourceDictionary` key type is string:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <my:ObjectToResourceConverter x:Key="StatusConverter">
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="True" UriSource="/TestProject;/Resources/Open.png"/>
            <BitmapImage x:Key="False" UriSource="/TestProject;/Resources/Closed.png" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </my:ObjectToResourceConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Desired code but doesn't compile due to:

> Unrecognized tag x:Key

`XAML`

```
... 
<BitmapImage UriSource="/TestProject;/Resources/Open.png">
    <x:Key>
        <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
    </x:Key>
</BitmapImage>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, yes, you usually can declare markup extensions with element syntax, but `x:Key` is actually a *directive*, not a markup extension. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742804.aspx), `x:Key` does not support element syntax in XAML 2006. If you use XAML 2009 it does, but it's unlikely that you are (or would want to).

But even if you could that, it wouldn't help, because (in XAML 2006; XAML 2009 might be different, didn't check) the key of a resource dictionary can only be set using  `string`, `x:Type`, or `x:Static`. So for your case, you would need to define a static property that produces `false`, and set that as the key using `x:Static`.

**Edit** The part about only supporting `string`, `x:Type`, and `x:Static` is not completely true. I was too trusting of the compiler error message (which says 'Only String, TypeExtension, and StaticExtension are supported.'). There is at least one other supported key type: [ComponentResourceKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753186.aspx). There may be more I'm forgetting or of which I am unaware. But in any case, arbitrary markup extensions (like a custom-defined one that returns a boolean) are not supported.